# Приложение C++ в Web

Tags: веб-программирование, c++

Имеется переносимый код приложения на C++, возможно ли встроить не геморно этот код на сайт, конечно, чтобы полностью работал, вместо того, чтобы писать всё по новому на JavaScript?

Comment: Надо же хотя бы, прежде чем упоминать C++ и JavaScript, понимать, что JavaScript - это язык сценариев, преимущественно обрабатываемый браузером на клиентской стороне, а C++ совершенно другая опера? И какой браузер имеет встроенный компилятор C++, чтобы парсить его "на лету"? Если это имелось ввиду.. Хотя не умолчу, что JavaScript может быть обработан на сервере, но тем не менее, это разные вещи.
Модули, написанные на C++, могут быть использованы (и используются на соответствующей платформе) для Web-приложений, но речи о простом "встраивании" C++ в сторонний проект вместо JavaScript - нонсенс.

Comment: Во-вторых: переносимый код. Это как "на деревню дедушке". Что делает этот код, чтобы его "встроить на сайт"? Вопрос слишком абстрактен, увы.

Comment: Да, на самом деле. Можно поподробнее. Я очень надеюсь, что автор имел ввиду именно c++ и node.js .

Comment: @void, существует возможность скопмилить нативный код под asm.js, но подробностей и ограничений я не знаю.

Comment: @dzhioev, есть много возможностей - я не отрицаю, просто вопрос автора не об этом. Автор, скорее всего, недопонимает технологии, и пытается представить себе что-то в собственном понимании, что раз есть некий пресловутый код, то его можно просто скопипейстить хоть на спутниковый ресивер и он должен работать - ведь код-то переносимый!

Answer (score 1):

[Можно.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm) Создаются CGI-программы на С++ Работает довольно шустро.

Comment: Можно, да. Можно и "ASP.NET with Managed C++". Но вопрос не в том, что можно что-то сделать, если делать с нуля CGI-программы на C++, а вопрос как раз в том, что у автора есть некий уже готовый код на C++, и автору не хочется ничего менять и портировать, а хочется просто "встроить" этот код "в сайт, чтобы полностью работал".

Comment: для примера, на чистом C, была/есть ,библиотека, cgihtml.

Comment: @void, написание небольшой обертки вокруг готового кода для его использования как приложение CGI/FastCGI, или же как модуля ноды/python/ruby/php - довольно тривиальная задача, которую вполне можно понимать под "просто встроить". Совсем же без написания кода - никак, да.